# Traer informacion diferente a null

Tags: javascript, fetch, null

Tengo una informacion en un googlesheet donde en la columna 63 dice Aprobado. Cuando clickeas ahi se abre un menu que te da la opcion YES y NO. El cliente define si acepta o no al postulante y en un fetch yo tengo un foreach

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
        if (row.c[7].v === "Organization" && row.c[63].v === "YES") {
          totalInfo.push(row.c)
        } else if (row.c[7].v === "Individual" && row.c[63].v === "YES") {
          totalInfo.push(row.c)
        }
      })
    })
```

El tema es que cuando se carga el postulante despues de pasar su informacion en el formulario ingresa con la columna Aprobado vacia. Hasta que el cliente no toca YES or No la pagina no carga nada y la funcion se rompe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

&& row.c[63]?.v === "YES"

Agregando el signo de pregunta chequeo si es null o no esa columna antes de preguntar por el yes